# how can i thoroughly change (key "C-x") in ivy-minibuffer-map?

Tags: key-bindings, ivy, prefix-keys

one thing very interesting,
i tried to

`(define-key ivy-minibuffer-map (kbd "C-x") 'ivy-kill-line)`

..well
then i restart my emacs, 
the first time i use the ivy to complete something,
i type C-x indeed can kill the line,

but ,the second time i use the ivy, the C-x became a suffix.
what the fuxk... then i tried which-key-mode,
i found these keys on suffix of C-x in ivy-minibuffer

1. C-x 8(iso-transl-ctl-8-map) -> (many strange chars inside..)
2. C-x @  -> (S -> event-apply-shift-modifier)(h -> event-apply-hyper-modifier)....etc something like this
3. C-x r -> (some functions on rectangle..)

but i never defined them...
what the fuxk...

anyone can help me out..
i just want to use C-x in ivy-minibuffer-map to kill the line.

btw, i tried this, doesnt work.

```
(defvar ivy-minibuffer-map (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))define xxxxx)
```

emmm.i think maybe this is caused by some other minor modes.
emmmm. confused.